# how to make one text hide another text.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing facebook's comments box and what i want is that the comments which i grab thru GET and render to template should be invisible to human but visible to search engines.

as experiment, i did this: http://jsfiddle.net/4D8hh/

how can i make `first` hide the `second`? but the `second` should stay crawlable.

z-index seems to be wrong choice here, with what else can i do it?is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:none` for anything you want to have on the page, but not have visible to the user.   The content will be there... it just won't "show" on the page.

Comment: really? the content will be there?

Comment: Yup... you can even view the page source code and you'll see the content is all there.   It's just hidden from human view"

Comment: oh thats awesome. isnot it bad or illegal for seo issues?

Comment: AFAIK display none wont work for google . :) and im quite sure about it .

Comment: @HusseinNazzal, so display:none will not be crawled?

Comment: Display:none is still crawlable by Google.  Take a look at this link:  http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/6fuh4oCDo10, notably this text = `links hidden by CSS and display:none are visible to bots and text-only browsers, but hidden to people by most browsers`

Comment: @Charlie74 good to know :) i really though it is not alloed . i cant remember where i read that though

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
background:white;
```

and that should be it

but qoura has some other wonderful idea please take a look here it works for them it should work for you . :)

https://plus.google.com/106413090159067280619/posts/KDSVtgHiuie

Answer (score 0):

May I raise my concern here. Google don't appreciate people are trying to get a better search ranking by hiding text. And it probably won't work at all. Seen from a user perspective, why don't you want the comments to be visible?

Anyway, if you really wanna go down this road, start using:
http://schema.org/Comment

And then you can take the elements out of context with position absolute:

```
position: absolute;
left: -9999em;
```

Or like Twitter Bootsrap, .sr-only:

```
.sr-only
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i am showing comments in facebooks comment box, but this is in iframe and wont be crawled, i need them to be crawled, so i thought, i would grap them thru graph api and put in content making only visible to crawler